# Passing Hash values as parameters to methods in Ruby

Tags: ruby, methods, hash, parameters

I have a method met1 that takes hash values as parameters.

For example: `met1('abc' => 'xyz')`

What should be the syntax when I define the method? Can it be something like this?

```
def met1(options)
  puts options
end
```

I know the above syntax works. But how can I access the individual hash key and value inside the `met1`? (where key is `abc` and value is `xyz`?) Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats easy

```
met1("abc" => "xyz")

def met1(options)
  puts options
  # with key
  puts options["abc"]
end
```

I assume you know what the options might contain in terms of keys right? if not,

```
def met1(options)
  puts options.keys # options is the hash you passed it, use it like one
end
```

Comment: In the second way where options.keys worked, how do I print the value without using options["abc"]?

Comment: By using "options.values" you can get hold of the values.

Comment: Go thru the Ruby Hash documentation. Hashes include the Enumerable module and you can use them a bit like arrays. You can do things like each, map, collect, reject etc on Hash structure. A very important class to understand and keep document handy when you're starting up with Ruby/Rails

Comment: Thank you Aditya Sanghi. I will do that

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is correct. simply use options['key'] (in case 'key' is a string) in your method. It's customary to use symbols as keys, so in your example:

```
met1(:abc => 'xyz')

def met1(options)
  puts options[:abc]
end
```

Comment: When I did that it said undefined local variable key

Comment: if key is a string you should write options['key']. if it is a symbol, you should write options[:key]